# why this following php code gives such result

Tags: php

When I echo the variable `$count` before `if else` , it shows 3. But in the `else` or after `if else`, it is giving 0. Could anybody help me , why it happens.

```
$arr = array(1,3,5);
$count = count($arr);
if ($count = 0) {
  echo "An array is empty.";
} else {
  echo "An array has $count elements.";
}
```

Comment: **Why not just** `if(empty($arr)){ ... } else { ... }`?

Comment: I can't remember ever seeing so many answers given for one measly missing `=` sign.

Comment: we all typed them at the same time, lol.

Comment: The clincher would come as *"it doesn't work"* --- Um... right. Let the OP pick & choose.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It was a bit embarrassing to watch. But who can resist low hanging fruit? Now let's see him pick an answer. That would be surprising....

Comment: @CodeAngry LOL! *"But who can resist low hanging fruit?"* --- Love it! Good one ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using assignment operator "=" instead of comparison operator "==".

To avoid this type of mistakes you should try

```
if(0 == $count) { // best practice to avoid assignment mistakes
```

Comment: +1 Finally, **a real answer**! Even thought if he'll ever compare 2 `$vars`, he's done for it. :)

Answer (score 3):

You used an assignment operator instead of an equality operator:

```
if ($count = 0) {
//         ^ You meant == or ===
```

[Read more about PHP operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use `===` to compare:

```
if ($count === 0) {
```

But an empty array is falsy, so you could do this without `count`:

```
$arr = array(1,3,5);
if ($arr) {
  echo "An array has elements.";
} else {
  echo "An array is empty.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
if ($count == 0) {
```

instead of $count = 0 inside if.

Answer (score 0):

You are using single equals to test for equality, when it actually means assignment.

Change to a double equals.

Answer (score 0):

`=` is assign operator ([assign](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)) and `==` is comparison ([comparison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)) operator.

change your condition to this:

try this:

```
if ($count == 0) {
```

or

```
 if ($count === 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change operator = to == in if condition.

```
 $arr = array(1,3,5);
    $count = count($arr);
    if ($count == 0) {
      echo "An array is empty.";
    } else {
      echo "An array has $count elements.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a comparison operator.

It is supposed to be:

```
if ($count == 0 )
```

Comment: `comparator operator` sounds AWESOME but it's `comparison operator`.